# How to find all checkedout files with ClearCase cleartool?

Tags: version-control, clearcase, cleartool

I'm trying to **setup our ClearCase with Hudson** for a continuous integration (and deployment later).

I finally got a UCM view for the build, but unfortunatly **our build process checks out files** to store the build number. **Now the build broke** and the file is still checked out, **preventing the next build**.

I already now about `cleartool find . -type f`, but I can't figure out how to find checked out files. I know the syntax of UNIX' find, so that isn't a problem.

Can someone point me to a documentation of the query language or maybe give an example to find checked out or hijacked files?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can start by this SO question on [how to list private files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369697/command-line-to-delete-all-clearcase-view-private-files/369952#369952).

Then it depends on the nature of your ClearCase view.
On a dynamic view for instance, a simple  `ct lsprivate` list private files (including hijacked ones) and checkout files.

The official command is [**`cleartool lscheckout`**](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lscheckout.htm) (or '`lsco`').
If you are within the right vob within your view:

```
$/path/to/view/vobs/aVob
cleartool lsco -rec -cview
```

,should list all checked out files from any user in any sub-directories of said vob.

But if your build is broken because of files checked out in *several* vobs, then you need to widen the scope:

```
$/path/to/view/
cleartool lsco -avobs -cview
```

(you don't need to be in a specific vob in this case)

---

As [Manjunath K Mayya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/447237/manjunath-k-mayya) points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092714/how-to-find-all-checkedout-files-with-clearcase-cleartool/3094806#comment111016946_3094806):

> To list only the file names, without the version details, we can use "`short`":
>
> ```
> cleartool lsco -short -avobs -cview
> ```

Comment: Good answer. If you want to select only your checkouts, you can execute the following command: `cleartool lsco -me -cview -avobs`

Comment: @DominiqueTerrs Indeed, as I already documented and illustrated in http://stackoverflow.com/a/1410536/6309 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/12186459/6309

Comment: @yellowantphil Thank you. I have updated the link accordingly.

Comment: To list only the file names, without the version details, we can use "short"
`cleartool lsco -short -avobs -cview`

Comment: @ManjunathKMayya Thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment in the answer, for more visibility.

Comment: With option `-all` instead of `-rec` you don't need to be in the root dir of the VOB. --- For more options see also [IBM's reference page](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/rational-clearcase/9.0.0?topic=ucm-lscheckout).

Comment: @MattTT True. I usually used it only in the context of a VOB.