# Best backup strategy for checked-out and hijacked files in all ClearCase VOBs and views

Tags: unix, scripting, clearcase

Our policy here is that only "most important" CCase views are backed up.
All the important data are considered to be in the VOBs and also under non-CCase directories, but never in views.

However, an special case are the checked-out files in views. 
People quite very often forget that they became private files in their dynamic view.
Some times they cannot be found easily (or at all) under the dynamic view storage area.
In snapshot views hijacked elements may become also important.

What is the best strategy to find and backup all those files only (checked-out / hijacked) in *every* (dynamic / snapshot) view and VOB ?.
(It should be possible to script it in very few lines, i think, ct lsco, ct lspriv ...).

Thank you very much in advance, Javier.
(FJCobas, Spain).

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to use the SO question "[Command line to delete all ClearCase view-private files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369697/command-line-to-delete-all-clearcase-view-private-files/369952#369952)", adapting it to select only checkout, hijacked and/or eclipsed files.

With Unix:

```
cleartool ls -r -nxn | grep -e "(CHECKEDOUT|hijacked|eclipsed)"
```

Note: as mentioned in the SO question "[ClearCase: Backup for only modified checked-out elements in all views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652854/clearcase-backup-for-only-modified-checked-out-elements-in-all-views/3653196#3653196)", an optimized solution would check if a checkout file actually introduced any changes. But if you have lots of checkouts, this wouldn't scale: a full copy (of *all* files) every time will be faster.

You can then copy them in a safe backup location.