# How to avoid repeat check outs on already checked out files or directories?

Tags: clearcase

I have some files and directories out of which few are already checked out and few are not.
To check out those uncheck out files I am running recursive checkout:

```
ct co -nc  ./*
```

Which gives below message for already checkout files or directory:

```
cleartool: Error: Element "abc/xyz" is already checked out to view "pqr".
```

Is there any way I can avoid performing `ct co` on already checked out files or directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can check if you have the same issue when applying my old method "[How do I perform a recursive checkout using ClearCase?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/119595/6309)".

```
 cleartool find somedir -type f -exec "cleartool checkout -c \"Reason for massive checkout\" \"%CLEARCASE_PN%\""
```

(which is mirrored by the [IBM technote swg21122520](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?&rs=984&uid=swg21122520))

The other option is to:

- first find checked out files (see "[How to find all checkedout files with ClearCase cleartool?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3094806/6309)", without the `-cview` option, in order to list checked out files in *all* views)
- redirect that `find` into a file

Then you can replace the -exec directive above in order, for each `\"%CLEARCASE_PN%\"` found, to:

- check if it is listed in the checked out files found in the previous point
- if it is not, proceed with the checkout.

In short: a two-step process.

Comment: Besides, I'd suggest to place more than one filename in "cleartool co" command (in order to save time)